# want to run redis-server in background nonstop

Tags: redis, juggernaut

I have downloaded redis-2.6.16.tar.gz file and i installed sucessfully. After installed i run src/redis-server it worked fine.

But i don't want manually run src/redis-server everytime, rather i want redis-server running as background process continuously.

So far after installed i did following tasks:

1. vim redis.conf and i changed to

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
  daemonize yes
```

But same result i found. What mistake i did?

After redis run in background. I will run juggernaut also as background process with following command.

```
nohup node server.js
```

But i am not able to make redis run in background. Please provide some solution.

Comment: What OS? After `sudo apt-get install redis-server` the server runs as you'd expect it too.

Comment: This is ubuntu OS, ok i will check this command.

Comment: Here too.  So why did you not install the package and be done with it?

Comment: As redis is already installed for installing with apt-get i have to uninstall my old one right, and with package i installed it before few month back it was working. So.

Comment: Thanks lot man, you saved my time. From today i will never use the package for redis installation.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Since Redis 2.6 it is possible to pass Redis configuration parameters using the command line directly. This is very useful for testing purposes.

```
redis-server --daemonize yes
```

Check if the process started or not:

```
ps aux | grep redis-server
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after this to see if its working on the background you could just use:
redis-cli ping

Comment: @AronisMariano and `PONG` for the response :)

Comment: And just add `alias redis-server='redis-server --daemonize yes'` to your `~/.bash_profile` then you will get daemonize every time you type `redis-server` to your command line.

Comment: I wish that this flag was in the --help documentation. This helped me to load this directly from python using subprocess: subprocess.Popen(['redis-server', '--daemonize', 'yes'])

Comment: This helped me solve a production error within seconds!

Comment: The inevitable followup is how to stop/close a daemonized redis-server. `redis-cli shutdown` works for me. See more with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249229/how-to-stop-a-redis-server-that-was-started-with-daemonize-yes/

Answer (score 17):

I think the best way is to use Redis' config file:

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
daemonize yes
```

Set `daemonize` to `yes` in the config file. Say the file is `~/.redis/redis.conf`, then just run

```
$ redis-server ~/.redis/redis.conf
```

And it just works.

Answer (score 10):

Or you can simply run it as `src/redis-server redis.conf&`

Comment: thanx i will make it try, for now problem get resolved.

Comment: You can also pass configuration values on the command line, refer to the Redis configuration documentation: http://redis.io/topics/config


To daemonize at the command line: redis-server --daemonize yes

Comment: More info on background jobs: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes

Answer (score 3):

For windows:

Step 1: Install redis as a service

```
redis-server --server-install
```

Step 2: Run background

```
redis-server --server-start
```

Answer (score 2):

To run redis server in background and ignore output .

```
nohup redis-server &
```

To check the server

```
ps aux | grep redis-server
```

To Kill server

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PM2 when you want to run an application in the background.

- Download pm2 package as global by npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

  - `npm i -g pm2`
- Then you can start the redis server.

  - `pm2 start "redis-server" --name redis-caching-session`

You can check pm2 sessions by `pm2 status` command and get logs of redis server by `pm2 logs redis-caching-server` command.

Edit: After 9 years, I just saw this post :) This answer may help other people so why I want to share.

Comment: Indeed, it will really help those who are using Node.js and process manager pm2. Thanks for your valuable feedback. +1