# Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused with homebrew

Tags: redis, redis-server

Using homebrew to install Redis but when I try to ping Redis it shows this error:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

**Note :** 
I tried to turn off firewall and edit conf file but still cannot ping.
I am using macOS Sierra and homebrew version 1.1.11

Answer (score 568, accepted):

After installing `redis`, type from `terminal`:

```
redis-server
```

And Redis-Server will be started

Comment: However, how do I stop it from listening to that port/host?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi Please Refer [How can I stop redis-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910378/how-can-i-stop-redis-server)

Comment: For windows from Command Prompt,

`cd C:\Program Files\Redis` and then

`redis-server`

Comment: how to run redis-server continuously in the background, I'm using ubuntu @LuFFy

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN, Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33316249/2087247), I hope it will help

Comment: It helps to run `brew install redis` first (fyi)

Comment: You have to add redis.exe path after installed it. You can add it from Control panel> System>A dvanced System Settings> Environment Variables> Path> Edit> New
and then restart your system and enjoy it.
My Redis path was: C:\Program Files\Redis

Comment: set `&` at the end of the command to run it in background

Answer (score 63):

I found this question while trying to figure out why I could not connect to redis after starting it via `brew services start redis`.

## tl;dr

Depending on how fresh your machine or install is you're likely missing a config file or a directory for the redis defaults.

1. You need a config file at `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf`. Without this file `redis-server` will not start. You can copy over the default config file and modify it from there with

   ```
   cp /usr/local/etc/redis.conf.default /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
   ```
2. You need `/usr/local/var/db/redis/` to exist. You can do this easily with

   ```
   mkdir -p /usr/local/var/db/redis
   ```

Finally just restart redis with `brew services restart redis`.

### How do you find this out!?

I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out if redis wasn't using the defaults through homebrew and what port it was on. Services was misleading because even though `redis-server` had not actually started, `brew services list` would still show redis as "started." The best approach is to use `brew services --verbose start redis` which will show you that the log file is at `/usr/local/var/log/redis.log`. Looking in there I found the smoking gun(s)

```
Fatal error, can't open config file '/usr/local/etc/redis.conf'
```

or

```
Can't chdir to '/usr/local/var/db/redis/': No such file or directory
```

Thankfully the log made the solution above obvious.

## Can't I just run `redis-server`?

You sure can. It'll just take up a terminal or interrupt your terminal occasionally if you run `redis-server &`. Also it will put `dump.rdb` in whatever directory you run it in (`pwd`). I got annoyed having to remove the file or ignore it in git so I figured I'd let brew do the work with services.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem on a laravel project where i was getting connection refused in abstractconnection.php line 155

Comment: I was having an error in abstractconnection.php line 155 too! Crazy.

Comment: Start with verbose did the thing for me. I was having an issue in redis.conf. Thanks

Comment: `brew services restart redis` was key for me here, all other conf files etc. were set up correctly- the service apparently was just in some trouble!

Answer (score 35):

```
redis-server --daemonize yes
```

I have solved this issue by running this command.

Comment: Usefull solution on ubuntu server after reloading

Answer (score 27):

If after install you need to run `redis` on all time, just type in terminal:

`redis-server &`

**Running redis using upstart on Ubuntu**

I've been trying to understand how to setup systems from the ground up on Ubuntu. I just installed `redis` onto the box and here's how I did it and some things to look out for.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

That will create a `redis` user and install the `init.d` script for it. Since `upstart` is now the replacement for using init.d, I figure I should convert it to run using `upstart`.

To disable the default `init.d` script for `redis`:

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-server disable
```

Then create `/etc/init/redis-server.conf` with the following script:

```
description "redis server"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown

exec sudo -u redis /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

respawn
```

What this is the script for `upstart` to know what command to run to start the process. The last line also tells `upstart` to keep trying to respawn if it dies.

One thing I had to change in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` is `daemonize yes` to `daemonize no`. What happens if you don't change it then `redis-server` will fork and daemonize itself, and the parent process goes away. When this happens, `upstart` thinks that the process has died/stopped and you won't have control over the process from within `upstart`.

Now you can use the following commands to control your `redis-server`:

```
sudo start redis-server
sudo restart redis-server
sudo stop redis-server
```

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 26):

This work for me :

```
sudo service redis-server start
```

Comment: this still works on ubuntu 16.04 and redis 6.0.6, great

Answer (score 18):

### Date: Dec 2021

There is a couple of reason for this error. I read one article to fix the issue for me. So I just summarize what to check one by one.

##### 1 Check: Redis-Server not Started

```
redis-server

Also to run Redis in the background, the following command could be used.

redis-server --daemonize yes
```

##### 2. Check: Firewall Restriction

```
sudo ufw status (inactive)
sudo ufw active (for making active it might disable ssh when first time active. So enable port 22 to access ssh.)
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow 6379
```

##### 3. Check: Resource usage

```
ps -aux | grep redis
```

##### 4. Config setup restriction

```
sudo vi /etc/redis/redis.conf.
```

Comment the following line.

```
# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

> Note: It will be more difficult for malicious actors to make requests or gain access to your server. Make sure you're bound to correct IP address network.

Hope it helps someone. For more information read the following article.

https://bobcares.com/blog/could-not-connect-to-redis-connection-refused/

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
sudo service redis-server restart
```

Comment: I am using Windows WSL Ubuntu, and keeps getting errors in my terminal.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

So tried everything on the top, it does not work especially in Windows. That's why tried restarting the redis service on the Ubuntu and works perfectly fine! That's all.

Answer (score 9):

It's the better way to connect to your redis.

At first, check the ip address of redis server like this.

> ps -ef | grep redis

The result is kind of " redis  1184   1   0   .... /usr/bin/redis-server 172.x.x.x:6379

And then you can connect to redis with -h(hostname) option like this.

> redis-cli -h 172.x.x.x

Answer (score 7):

I found solution on github with my case when I try cmd redis-cli then throw "Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused"

cause: Worth noting, if you're in production, you might want to run Redis in the background

you can try cmd below to resolve issue

redis-server --daemonize yes

Comment: Thank you, this helped me start radis on my local machine running ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck on this for a long time. After a lot of tries I was able to configure it properly.

There can be different reasons of raising the error. I am trying to provide the reason and the solution to overcome from that situation. Make sure you have installed `redis-server` properly.

1. `6379 Port` is not allowed by ufw firewall.

   *Solution*: type following command `sudo ufw allow 6379`
2. The issue can be related to permission of `redis` user. May be redis user doesn't have permission of modifying necessary `redis` directories. The `redis` user should have permissions in the following directories:

   - `/var/lib/redis`
   - `/var/log/redis`
   - `/run/redis`
   - `/etc/redis`

   To give the owner permission to `redis` user, type the following commands:

   - `sudo chown -R redis:redis /var/lib/redis`
   - `sudo chown -R redis:redis /var/log/redis`
   - `sudo chown -R redis:redis /run/redis`
   - `sudo chown -R redis:redis /etc/redis`.

   Now restart `redis-server` by following command:

   `sudo systemctl restart redis-server`

Hope this will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 6):

Error connecting Redis on Apple Silicon( Macbook Pro M1 - Dec 2020), you have to just know 2 things:

1. Run the redis-server using a sudo will remove the server starting error

`shell% sudo redis-server`

2. For running it as a service "daemonize" it will allow you to run in the background

`shell% sudo redis-server --daemonize yes`

Verify using below steps:
`shell% redis-cli ping`

Hope this helps all Macbook Pro M1 users who are really worried about lack of documentation on this.

Comment: Thanks, I am on an Intel MacBook and this worked for me. first, run `redis-server --daemonize yes` and then `redis-cli ping` for a pong or just `redis-cli` to run quick commands in the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you need to run "redis-server &" after instalation to start the service, when you only run "redis-server" the service runs in undetached mode. emphasis on "&"

Answer (score 3):

First you need to up/start the all the redis nodes using below command, one by one for all conf files.
@Note : if you are setting up cluster then you should have 6 nodes, 3 will be master and 3 will be slave.redis-cli will automatically select master and slave out of 6 nodes using --cluster command as shown in my below commands.

```
[xxxxx@localhost redis-stable]$ redis-server xxxx.conf
```

then run

```
[xxxxx@localhost redis-stable]$ redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 --cluster-replicas 1
```

output of above should be like:

```
    >>> Performing hash slots allocation on 6 nodes...
```

2nd way to set up all things automatically:
 you can use utils/create-cluster scripts to set up every thing for you like 
starting all nodes, creating cluster
you an follow https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same problem because I had used improper syntax in my config file. I meant to add:

`maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru`

to my config file, but instead only added:

`allkeys-lru`

which evidently prevented Redis from parsing the config file, which in turn prevented me from connecting through the cli. Fixing this syntax allowed me to connect to Redis.

Answer (score 2):

Had that issue with `homebrew MacOS` the problem was some sort of permission missing on `/usr/local/var/log` directory [see issue here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/14192)

In order to solve it I deleted the `/usr/local/var/log` and reinstall redis `brew reinstall redis`

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to connect my Redis running in wsl2 from vs code running in Windows.

I have listed down what worked for me and the order in which I have performed these actions:

```
1) sudo ufw allow 6379
2) Update redis.conf to bind 127.0.0.1 ::1 192.168.1.7
3) sudo service redis-server restart
```

NOTE: This is the first time I have installed Redis on wsl2 and have not run a single command yet.

Let me know if it works for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My soulution just was to `systemctl enable redis-server`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was the password that contained some characters like `'`, after changing it the server started without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43323702/4751173), in my case `brew services list` claimed redis was running, but it wasn't. I found the following information in my log file at `/usr/local/var/log/redis.log`:

```
4469:C 28 Feb 09:03:56.197 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
4469:C 28 Feb 09:03:56.197 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=4469, just started
4469:C 28 Feb 09:03:56.197 # Configuration loaded
4469:M 28 Feb 09:03:56.198 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
4469:M 28 Feb 09:03:56.199 # Creating Server TCP listening socket 192.168.161.1:6379: bind: Can't assign requested address
```

That turns out to be caused by the following configuration:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1 192.168.161.1
```

which was necessary to give my VMWare Fusion virtual machine access to the redis server on macOS, the host. However, if the virtual machine wasn't started, this binding failure caused redis not to start up *at all*. So starting the virtual machine solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04
I have just entered this command in CMD
`sudo systemctl start redis-server`
And it is now working. so I think my Redis server was not started which is why it was showing me the error
*Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused*.

Answer (score 1):

**Redis for Mac:**

1- brew install redis
2- brew services start redis
3- redis-cli ping

```
$ brew services start redis 
$ brew services stop redis
$ brew services restart redis
```

Lunch autostart options:

```
$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
# autostart activate
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
# autostart deactivate
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Redis conf default path : /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone had come along and incorrectly edited the redis.conf file to this:

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
bind 192.168.1.7
```

when, it really needed to be this (one line):

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1 192.168.1.7
```

Comment: This is on a new install though, so I don't think the issue is a weird redis.conf.