# How to start Redis within Ubuntu run via CircleCI

Tags: docker, ubuntu, redis, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have the following CircleCI config (this is trimmed, I don't include the config after the failing line):

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/mycompany/mycompany_app
    docker:
    - image: ubuntu:18.04
    steps:
    - run:
        name: Update yum cache
        command: apt-get update
    - run:
        name: Install base packages
        command: apt-get install -y sudo git wget tzdata postgresql postgresql-contrib build-essential python2.7 make gcc redis-server
    - run:
        name: Start Redis
        command: sudo service redis-server start
    - run: redis-cli ping
```

The last command, `redis-cli ping` gives me the error `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`

The best thread I've been able to find on this issue is https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/365 though that doesn't help since I'm doing the manual start as they suggest. There's also some stuff in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781814/2518231) that's related, but I don't think not using `upstart` is my problem.

How can I get the server started so that it will answer to the ping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing `sudo service redis-server start` to `sudo redis-server --daemonize yes` which was indeed an option listed in the linked Github issue, though I had thought it was equivalent (for my purposes) to `redis-server &` so I hadn't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

To really take advantage of CircleCI though, you might want to try doing it like this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/mycompany/mycompany_app
    docker:
      - image: ubuntu:18.04
      - image: circleci/redis:4.0.9
    steps:
    - run:
        name: Update Apt Cache
        command: apt-get update
    - run:
        name: Install base packages
        command: apt-get install -y sudo git wget tzdata postgresql postgresql-contrib build-essential python2.7 make gcc
    - run: redis-cli ping
```

Comment: Does seem to work :(

`====>> redis-cli ping
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
redis-cli ping
/bin/bash: redis-cli: command not found
Error: Exited with code 127
Step failed
Error: runner failed
Task failed`

Comment: I had the same issues trying to get postgres running in a side image - ended up installing that manually as well

Comment: Depending on what your build is doing, you might be accessing the DB too fast. The `dockerize` command is available to wait for the DB port to be available before trying to use it.

Comment: Seems simpler to just create my own custom container with the dbs already installed and then just go from there. Thanks for the info on `dockerize` though!