# Redis keeps failing on Windows 10 with Node.JS : Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, windows-10

Consider the code :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const redis = require("redis");
const util = require("util");

const redisUrl = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379";
const client = redis.createClient(redisUrl);
client.hget = util.promisify(client.hget);
const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;

mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function(options = {}) {
  this.useCache = true;
  this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || "");
  return this; // now it's chainable
};

   ... // More code ...
```

It produces :

> events.js:173
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event [0]       ^ [0] [0] Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:6379 [0]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14) [0] Emitted 'error' event at: [0]     at
>   RedisClient.on_error
>   (C:\Development-X220\NODEJS\Redis\node_modules\redis\index.js:341:14)
>   [0]     at Socket.
>   (C:\Development-X220\NODEJS\Redis\node_modules\redis\index.js:222:14)
>   [0]     at Socket.emit (events.js:196:13) [0]     at emitErrorNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8) [0]     at emitErrorAndCloseNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3) [0]     at
>   processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) [0]
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

And also :

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

I've tried to run redis-server from CMD of Windows-10 and got :

```
'redis-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also followed on the suggestions people offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857551/could-not-connect-to-redis-at-127-0-0-16379-connection-refused-with-homebrew) but nothing worked.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

OK , I've fixed it by going to this link :

https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

I'm posting the stages for anyone who might encounter the same problem :

> Picking the top EXE file and installing it.
>
> After that in Windows 10 , hit : FN + R
>
> Type : services.msc
>
> Look for the "Redis Server" in the list , right click and choose
>   "Start".
>
> That's it , you're up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install software before using it, this is how it has been for recent 50 years. Consider [this guide](https://redislabs.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/a-3-2-installing-redis-on-window/) on installing Redis on Windows.

Comment: Did it already , installed Redis on my machine from here : https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

Comment: The `'redis-server' is not recognized...` means something went wrong, double check your installation.

Answer (score 0):

> 'redis-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

that means your redis server is not running yet so the timeout error is kind of expected.

redis for windows is not official i think so it's best you run redis in docker or a linux host.