# How to stop a redis server that was started with --daemonize yes

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, redis

I'm trying to kill a redis server that was started with  --daemonize yes

I feel like this should be easy, but I am unable to successfully kill it based on standard methods.  I'm using Redis 3.2 installed via these instructions: https://www.hugeserver.com/kb/install-redis-debian-ubuntu/

```
$ redis-server --daemonize yes 
1550:C 13 Mar 05:54:55.436 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1550:C 13 Mar 05:54:55.437 # Redis version=4.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1550, just started
1550:C 13 Mar 05:54:55.437 # Configuration loaded
$ kill 1550
-bash: kill: (1550) - No such process
$ kill -9 1550
-bash: kill: (1550) - No such process
$ killall redis-server
redis-server(1181): Operation not permitted
redis-server: no process found
$ /etc/init.d/redis-server stop
[....] Stopping redis-server (via systemctl): redis-server.service==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to stop 'redis-server.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
```

Why should I need to enter a password to stop it?  I never set a password when i started it.  And why doesn't kill work?  Even if I sudo it, it just restarts again after.

-------------------EDIT-------------------

Additional information.  Using the kill command on the process ID doesn't work.  I have to use sudo kill  but then it comes back with another processid as if something restarts it. I just killed it 3 times and it's back again with a 4th processid –

---------- Solution thanks to @Kevin Law ----------

I needed to kill the daemonized service and then kill the process.  Not just one or the other...

```
ubuntu@ip-MyIPAddress:~/Relayer$ ps -ef | grep redis-server
ubuntu    2381     1  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 redis-server *:6379
ubuntu    2386  1358  0 18:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis-server
ubuntu@ip-MyIPAddress:~/Relayer$ sudo service redis-server stop
ubuntu@ip-MyIPAddress:~/Relayer$ ps -ef | grep redis-server
ubuntu    2381     1  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 redis-server *:6379
ubuntu    2418  1358  0 18:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis-server
ubuntu@ip-MyIPAddress:~/Relayer$ kill 2381
ubuntu@ip-MyIPAddress:~/Relayer$ ps -ef | grep redis-server
ubuntu    2420  1358  0 18:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis-server
ubuntu@ip-MyIPAddress:~/Relayer$
```

Comment: Run `TOP` command and get the process id of `redis` process then try to kill it.

Comment: @BhushanPatil It doesn't seem to work.  I have to use sudo kill <processid> but then it comes back with another processid as if something restarts it.  I just killed it 3 times and it's back again with a 4th processid

Comment: Check if that redis process has parent process by `ps -o ppid= {pid}`, if so then kill that parent process as well.

Comment: Tried using ps -o ppid=, did I do that correctly?  See my edit above.

Comment: Can you try by `kill -9 {parent_process_id}` ?

Comment: That doesn't work either.  Kills it but it restarts.  I used the parent process ID according to the pstree results above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are three options for your question from my test.

1. Stop redis by stoping redis service. This is the recommend way in most cases.

```sh
sudo systemctl stop redis-server
```

or

```
sudo service redis-server stop
```

2. connect to this redis-server and shutdown it by redis-cli.

```
redis-cli
```

after connected to redis, issue shutdown to turn off redis-server

```
shutdown
```

3. Kill the redis-server process directly:

```
ps -ef | grep redis-server
kill -9 (pid)
```

Comment: systemctl stop redis-server   asks me for a password. But I didn't set a password, so what should I enter? service redis-server stop   does the same thing

Comment: prefixing your command with `sudo`. **systemd** command without sufficient privilege will ask for a password.

Comment: What password is it though?  This is a fresh EC2 instance without a password set...

Comment: If you got a fresh EC2 instance just prefixing **systemctl** with **sudo**, according to the default setting, you are not required to input password.

Comment: I've updated my answer and 2 options all have been tested on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for helping.  So the option 2 in your updated answer doesn't work.  It does kill it, but it immediately restarts with another processid. Your option 1 actually does the same thing.  I see:  127.0.0.1:6379> shutdown
not connected> 
not connected> 

But then it restarts with another process Id...  Is it possible I have a bad version of redis?

Comment: It's daemonized So I think something in Ubuntu is restarting it.  Maybe sysctl?

Comment: Ok.  I solved it, with your amazing help.  Thank you!  Your original answer was correct.  But it was a 2 step process and i was confused.

See my edits above.  Go ahead and edit your answer back to what it was originally  and ill accept it.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you, I added back my previous option and keep other two options in case someone needs it, they could be options according to my experience.

Comment: Just letting people know that `redis-cli shutdown` works for me on Mac/zsh

Answer (score 1):

Try following command to find the redis-server instances that are running and then try killing the exact instance with **kill** command.

```
ps -aef | grep redis
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  See my edits above.  It restarts itself after I kill it.

Comment: Can you check is there any parent process being executed for the same try **pkill process** for the same,where process should be name instead of pid.

Comment: That didn't work either.  Same results.  It tried using pstree to see the parent process, but it seems the one i'm killing is the parent process.

Comment: Ohh !! will check if i get something for the same will get back to you.